# Is there a way to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk if you are not using git?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, sbt, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am developing an Elastic Beanstalk app. It is a Scala web application, built with `sbt`. I want to deploy the resulting WAR from the command line to an existing environment.

All I can find is the `eb` CLI which appears to require you to use git: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-started.html

Is there not a way to simply specify a WAR and environment name to perform the deployment?

What is the best workaround otherwise? I can upload to S3 from the command line and then use the web app to choose that file, but it's a bit more painful than I wanted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Elastic Beanstalk CLI (`eb`)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html) instead of AWS CLI. Just run `eb create` to create a new environment and `eb deploy` to update your environment.

You can set specific artifact (your `*.war` file), by configuring the EB CLI (read: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact):

> You can tell the EB CLI to deploy a ZIP or WAR file that you generate
>   as part of a separate build process by adding the following lines to
>   .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml in your project folder.
>
> ```
> deploy:   
>   artifact: path/to/buildartifact.zip
> ```

Comment: Finally got to try this, thanks! It worked. I guess I was confused by all the front-loading of git into the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I found a way - use the `aws` CLI instead. First upload to S3 (I actually use `s3cmd`) then create an application version:

```
$ aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name untaggeddb --version-label myLabel --source-bundle S3Bucket="bucketName",S3Key="key.war"
```

I believe the application version can then be deployed with `update-environment` also using the `aws` CLI.